# How to apply updates from a factory to view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I am trying to change a reference in my factory in an asyn mode, and i don't see the changes been updated in my view.

View

```
<div ng-repeat="Message in Current.Messages">{{Message.text}}</div>
```

Controller

```
angular.module('test').controller('testCtrl', function($scope, Service) {
  $scope.Current = Service.Current;
});
```

Factory

```
angular.module('test').factory('Service', function($rootScope) {
  var Service = function() {
    this.Current = { Messages: [] };
    this.Socket = io.connect(/* ... */);
  }

  Service.prototype.asyncEvent = function(Another) {
    this.Socket.on('event', function() {
      $rootScope.$apply(function() {
        this.Current = Another; // After this change, i would like my view to display the new object but nothing happens...
      }.bind(this));
    });
  };

  var service = new Service();
  return service;
});
```

When i try do to a `.push()` instead of changing the reference, it works well, so i know the issue is not realted to the async thing. 
However i don't see how i could use a referecence from my factory to my view, and being able to change the object i point to at any time.

Comment: Where is `Message` property on `Current` @ `Service.Current.Message`? or did you mean `$scope.Current = Service.Current`

Comment: After your update `$scope.Current` has Messages and you are doing Current.Messages in the view?

Comment: @PSL you are right, i have updated my post.

Comment: Instead of doing `this.Current = Another;` what happens when you do `this.Current.Messages = Another.Messages;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are overwriting the reference of `Current` with a new object reference by doing `this.Current = Another;`, so reference of Current held by `$scope.Current` @ `$scope.Current = Service.Current` has the old object reference. So it does not get reflected. There could be multiple object hierarchy you can introduce to solve this issue, especially when you expose a property from a service and you expect it be used by the consumer as a live property, you could share a reference that does not change.

As a simple fix in your case you could do `this.Current.Messages = Another.Messages;` instead of `this.Current = Another;`, so that you do not change the reference held by `serviceInstance.Current` property during the service instantiation, instead you change only the Messages Array.

Try:-

```
angular.module('test').factory('Service', function($rootScope) {
  var Service = function() {

    this.Current = { Messages: [] };
    this.Socket = io.connect(/* ... */);
  }

  Service.prototype.asyncEvent = function(Another) {
    this.Socket.on('event', function() {
      $rootScope.$apply(function() {
        this.Current.Messages = Another.Messages; 
      }.bind(this));
    });
  };

  var service = new Service();
  return service;
});
```

But you should be careful when you expose properties from a service it can easily be overwritten accidentally or otherwise by another consumer (controller) and that could cause data integrity issues in your application. instead expose methods, implement promise patterns to pass around the data and even you could use pub/sub pattern (or even use angular built in event bus) to let the consumer know of the occurrence of an event.

Comment: It works well, thanks !
I am not a fan of this method either, could you tell me, even brifly how i could implement a promise pattern in this case ?
Thanks for your help !

Comment: @Ludo Great!! SInce this answered your specific issue, do you mind accepting it. For your question, Who perform the asyncEvent? basically what i am saying one of your component raises the event that refreshes the data right?, the same event can be caught by another component which tell it to get refreshed data which would be your getData method which returns a promise that resolves with the data.